# Where is this dark-haired girl in lingerie from?

Tags: itasha

I'm looking for the source of this girl on this itasha picture I found. I can't see the words on the hood due to the profile aspect of the photo.

[image]

[Original Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?sa=N&hl=en&biw=1366&bih=633&q=itasha%20cars&tbm=isch&tbs=simg:CAQSigEahwELEKjU2AQaAAwLELCMpwgaYgpgCAMSKMoNvATMDcQNyw3DDcYNwATBDdYN9iD-IOwgoCbOPIom_1SD0IPsg_1CAaMNJCuljINSn9obb9Alw-OPCAJqR3AnCBBcRSXNxiSTZX8vJswre3JmVwE2_1Z9LrmuyADDAsQjq7-CBoKCggIARIEdYMB5Aw&ved=0ahUKEwj4nOCA0dDJAhVD1WMKHYfyDO8Q2A4IGygB#imgrc=b3KZkGYe1VhEpM%3A)

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the original character [Sakurako Mitsuki](http://minkara.carview.co.jp/en/userid/1534925/blog/27356570/).

[image: Sakurako Mitsuki]

The car seems to a Mitsubishi Lancer Evo VII, in case you're wondering.

That photo was taken at an itasha carshow in the Akihabara UDX parking garage around December of 2012.